# When are OpenCL 2.0's pipes useful?

Tags: opencl, specifications

OpenCL 2.0 introduced a new feature, pipes. When would this be useful? Are there types of applications where you would benefit from pipes? Are there hardware architectures which are more suitable?

Answer (score 2):

It should be very useful for some streaming processing use cases. You can think one keep producing some data which is being consumed by the other one.

Answer (score 1):

A typical use case is that the output from one kernel will be used as input to a second kernel. So the first kernel produces data, the second consumes it. For some applications producer and consumer kernels can run in concurrently. An OpenCL pipe memory object facilitates such applications, whereby it can handle serially and concurrently executed producer-consumer kernels.

Here is an example: a first kernel applies some image processing steps (such as convolution), the second one calculates a histogram.

A book on this topic I personally like is *Heterogeneous Computing with OpenCL 2.0* by David R. Kaeli, Perhaad Mistry, Dana Schaa, Dong Ping Zhang.